# How to automate conversion of raster NoData values?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, spatial-analyst, raster-calculator, iterator

I am doing the work of change all null pixels to a value of -1 in the raster file X with raster calculator by using following syntax:

```
Con(IsNull("X"),-1,"X")
```

However, I need to do the same work on >200 raster files. Is there any other method so that I can do these works simply?

Answer (score 2):

[ModelBuilder](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Tutorial_Executing_tools_in_ModelBuilder/002w0000007t000000/) is all that you need.

You have to loop through your layers with iterator ([Iterate Rasters](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00400000000z000000.htm)).

Answer (score 2):

You can automate this using Python and the [Con (Spatial Analyst)](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//009z00000005000000) function.

```
import arcpy
from arcpy.sa import *
arcpy.CheckOutExtension = "Spatial"

arcpy.env.workspace = "C:/temp/data"
outws = "C:/temp/out"

rasters = arcpy.ListRasters()

for r in rasters:
    inras = Raster(r)
    outCon = Con(IsNull(inRas), -1, inRas)
    outCon.save(os.path.join(outws, r))
```